# M2 Multistore maximum limit

Tags: magento2, multistore

For my new project i need to create 3000 stores using magento multistore in same magento installation. **Anyone knows what is limit for maximum numbers of stores in magento2?  Or what would be the right approach to do that?**

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not has any limit for create multi stores. You can create **n** number of stores in the same **instance**.

However if you need to create just multiple store views I don't assume there will be any problem in case of performance. But in case of **multi website** you may face some issue regarding **performance**. The **Indexing** may cause load as it may all **depend** on your **websites, Products, Customer Groups, Taxes**. So these factors may cause performance issue in your website.

This things can also be achieved but you may need to create a good server and balancing performance structure.